# Unable to open applications with SysNative alias path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a 32-bit installation of Python 3.4.3 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine, which is causing some issues with the automatic x64 redirection. Rather than disable and enable redirection, I'm using the SysNative alias to access the System32 directory.

Here's the issue. If I check the validity of a path, as follows:

```
import os

os.path.exists(r'C:\WINDOWS\SYSNATIVE\osk.exe')
```

I get a return of 'True'. However, if I try and open the application, using either os or subprocess:

```
import os

os.popen(r'C:\WINDOWS\SYSNATIVE\osk.exe')
```

I get 'The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again." I've tried running as Administrator, which has no effect.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\StarCraft II\\StarCraft II.exe"])
```

or:

```
import os
os.system('"C:/Program Files (x86)/StarCraft II/StarCraft II.exe"')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've actually tried all forms of calling/running an external program, including those you've listed. I still receive the 'The system cannot find the file..." error regardless of the function I use.

Comment: The problem is with SYSNATIVE I'm getting the same thing with launchy trying to open iis management console.